# Is the usage of "yours" like this grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage

"Yours is a new car"
I have never seen or heard the use of "yours" like this before today, is this sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is grammatically correct. The pronoun 'yours' can refer to something that comes before or after - this applies to 'yours' and the other strong (or absolute) possessive pronouns - yours is a new car; mine is the black dog; hers is a red bicycle; his is a big house; theirs are nice hats; ours was the victory; its was the red roof (of a house).

> yours
>
> pronoun (PERSON/PEOPLE ADDRESSED) ​
>
> the one(s) belonging to
>   or connected with the person or group of people being spoken or
>   written to:
>
> Is this pen yours?
>   Unfortunately my legs aren't as long as yours.
>   I've  got something of yours (= that belongs to you).
>   **Yours is** the room on the top floor, on the left.

[Yours (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yours)

[Possessive pronouns](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/possessive-pronouns.html)